# How to manipluate files in laravel before they outputs to user?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I wanted to know how can I do something like that:
To have a file named `lang.json`
to put it anywhere in my laravel directory
when the user enter to `public/lang.json`  wrap the content inside this file in `JSON.parse()` ?

I know hot to do it in pure php
Just to `readfile` and then wrap it with this command and than output it to a user.
But how can I achive that behvior with laravel ?

Comment: You should invest some time in going through some beginners tutorials in laravel. Laracasts has some fantastic video tutorials, here's a link to a free series - (subscription is worth every penny) https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals. And by the way Laravel is php so you can still use your earlier workflow of reading a file and parsing it from within any of controller's actions/methods. Good luck with learning Laravel - its awesome.

Answer (score 0):

There we have a File class  to deal with files so in order to get contents of a file you just need to call in your controller:

```
  $file_contents = \File::get('some_file.json');
  $decoded = json_decode( \File::get('some_file.json') ); // or this way
```

also you may find usefull such method as

```
 \File::exists('some_file.json')
```

Finaly:

```
 if(\File::exists('some_file.json'){
  $decoded = json_decode( \File::get('some_file.json') );
 }
```

Note that it gets relative to public directory path, so when you give it 'some_file.json'  it expects it to be placed in public/some_file.json